# Similar method to /etc/init.d

Tags: centos, scripting, init-script

I have set my script to run using the `/etc/init.d` method. All works good. The problem is that my script does packet capturing and when it restarts the machine after say the `crond` is loaded then it loads this script of mine and the packet capture process I guess starting then and it halts from going further. Is there any method where I can force it only to start when Linux is fully loaded ?

Below is how my script looks like.

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 95 05
# myapp daemon
# description: myapp daemon
# processname: myapp

DAEMON_PATH="/usr/local/bin/"
DAEMON=pc1.c
#DAEMONOPTS="-my opts"
NAME=pc1.c
DESC="my packet capture"

PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

case "$1" in
start)
    printf "%-50s" "Starting $NAME..."
    insmod /usr/local/pfring/kernel/pf_ring.ko
    /usr/local/bin/pc1.c &
    $! > PIDFILE    
;;
status)
        if [ -f $PIDFILE]; 
        then if [ -d /proc/cat $PIDFILE ]; 
             then echo "Process is running"; 
             fi; 
        else echo "Error! PID file is missing!"; 

        fi

;;
stop)
        printf "%-50s" "Stopping $NAME"
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            cd $DAEMON_PATH
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            kill -HUP $PID
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
            rm -f $PIDFILE
        else
            printf "%s\n" "pidfile not found"
        fi
;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start 
;;
*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "fully loaded"? It may simply be that you are starting your init script before the network, or something similar.

Comment: @What I mean by fully loaded is that where the os is loaded after all the initialisation process.

Comment: In the init system in CentOS 5 and 6, everything is loaded one after the other. You simply need to make sure your service is numbered after all of the initialization you want to happen first.

Comment: I have updated my question with the /etc/init.d script. So what should I tweak here.

Comment: See the line `# chkconfig: 2345 95 05`? The "95" is the order in which it will start. Look at `/etc/rc3.d/S*` (or `rc5.d` if you're booting to a GUI) -- everything that's numbered after 95 will load before your service starts. (This is assuming you've enabled this script with the `chkconfig` command.)

Comment: @Should I set a bigger number so that it will start the last after the network n rest of the service have been started?

Comment: Yes, although I think the sorting is actually alphabetical — 99 is the largest practical number. And 95 should be well after network, which is normally at _10_. So, I kind of suspect that your actual problem is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would run the command that runs within your init.d script with '&' after the end of the command, it will become a background process, and the next services could start.

If you want the script to run as the final step (it would still block if it does not background) of your boot process, you could run it through /etc/rc.local (or your distro equivalent if you don't have one...)

Comment: @I dont quite get this method "with '&' after the end of the command, it will become a background process, and the next services could start." When you say background means it will not start immedialtely after my os is loaded ?

Comment: @biz14 A background process, in a nutshell (from a user point of view), is a process that starts executing immediately, and returns you your controlling terminal - so you are not 'communicating' with it anymore. So next the commands on the script file continue to operate; If there are none left, the script would end, and then init will run the next script...

Comment: @I have updated my question with my /etc/init.d script so what changes to do. I am lost between the init.d and background?

Comment: @biz14     /usr/local/bin/myap1.c  would become:     /usr/local/bin/myap1.c &

Comment: Ok I will do the necessary but I want to learn what is difference of having the & I know it will run into a background programme. But what is the key difference with what I am doing now?

Comment: @biz14 Right now you're simply executing a program that you wrote. The program has inputs (STDIN) and outputs (STDOUT, STDERR) - and it communicates with you through your terminal. Since your program is still running (you probably have a main() loop?) - you're still communicating with it through the terminal. Since you never exited your program, the controlling terminal is busy with it, and cannot continue running future commands. Backgrounding a process changes that - you get your terminal back and further commands can be run. Take a look at the fork() system call.

Comment: I guess backgrounding is the best here right? But I can still monitor it right. The reason why I need this method is because it should be creating a pid file and I can use tools like monit to monitor it and incase its down I can restart it. What do you think of my idea here?

Comment: @biz14 Backgrounding a process and then echo $! > PIDFILE is a very common practice in the Unix world :)

Comment: @Must I do this $! > PIDFILE ? Another thing if you see in my script I have commented this part #PID=`$DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!` and the rest of the part is not working. So I cant read the pid either. Any reason for this?

Comment: @biz14 That's because you're not doing $! > PIDFILE... You're doing some stuff I don't really understand. Basically if your PID file is stored in the variable PIDFILE (in your example that would be /var/run/myap1.c.pid)- the proper command, immediately after the background execution, would be: echo $! > $PIDFILE - and this is where the start) section of the script should end. Then, in the status section, I would use something like (untested code,to give idea): if [ -f $PIDFILE]; then if [ -d /proc/`cat $PIDFILE` ]; then echo "Process is running"; fi; else echo "Error! PID file is missing!"; fi

Comment: Note that the grey part in my last comment is originally backticks surrounding the part in grey.

Comment: I will test and get back to you if it works accordingly. Should I name the script with an extension with .sh or leave it without any extension ?

Comment: @biz14 Usually scripts in /etc/init.d are without extension. Extensions are meaningless in Unix. The script being in /etc/init.d already suggests that it's a script. It's really your choice, as, like I said, the extension itself is meaningless. To be executable, the script needs to be chmod +x - the rest does not matter.

Comment: @I tried and it holds my terminal where I cant do anything or even press any key on my terminal anymore.

Comment: @biz14 When you say "It", which part do you mean... (sorry that I can't chat, this is the first time I am on stackexchange ever, so no reputation :))

Comment: I mean the moment I start my service pc.sh start I can see my terminal printout some output and there after I cant control the terminal

Comment: @biz14 And you did add the & after your command? Please give the full script as it looks now...

Comment: I have update my question now with my latest script. Please review. Thank you. I also dont see anything in my top which indicate its running either.

Comment: @biz14 you forgot "echo" before $! and you also didn't enclose the cat $PIDFILE with backticks on both ends

Comment: do you mean like this cat `  $PIDFILE   `  I know without the extra spacing rite

Comment: @biz14 Nevermind, there are many errors there. Here, I did my best: http://pastebin.com/xjtzEfDF (I have no way to test, but see the things I changed...)

Comment: @The very first I tried service pc.sh start it say unrecognized then I stop and start it works. But surprisingly it does not show up in the top ? Any reason for this ??

Comment: @biz14 Maybe it doesn't consume many resources. top only shows you the most using processes on the system... and it can't fit them all on your screen (try 'htop' for a scrollable top). You should: ps axu | grep pc1

Comment: @htop is not working on my centos 6.4 but ps axu | grep pc1 does shows it

Comment: @Ok it is working fine now the problem it terminal is keep showing the printf from the script. Isnt it suppose to run in the background ?

Comment: Running in the background does not disconnect stdout/stderr from the terminal that ran the process. If you want to do that, then: `$DAEMON_PATH/$DAEMON > /var/log/mydaemon.log 2>&1 &` (if you don't want the output logged at all, replace `/var/log/mydaemon.log` with `/dev/null`)

Comment: b.t.w. If you have 64 bit: `rpm -i http://pkgs.repoforge.org/htop/htop-1.0.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm`

If you have 32 bit: `rpm -i http://pkgs.repoforge.org/htop/htop-1.0.2-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm`

for htop :)

Comment: thank you for the in depth information.Another thing from your experience what is the best tool to do monitoring for my script?

Comment: @Something funny happening now because suddenly each time I run my script and then I run top I see 2 instance of pc1.c any reason for this?

Comment: A simple cron could do the job (you can even have a part in the init script that is just like 'status', but if the if says /proc/PID doesn't exist, just run $0 start)... or, you could use monit which is simple enough. I don't know why it runs more than once. Maybe you simply ran the startup script twice. Currently there's no test in your script to NOT run the daemon again if it's already running. You should add that - again - just like 'status', and only if the if returned that there's no PID file OR that there is a PID file but no process, only then, run your daemon.

Comment: @I dont get you here about just run $0 start where to modify in the init ? I am sure there no are start up scripts are running. I am running your final copy which you gave me yesterday. I only ran this once service pc.sh start. Nothing else was done.

Comment: @biz14 add another section. `monitor)`  that will do the same thing like the `status)` section, but in case it detects PID is down (by if, just like in `status)` section), run the command `$0 start`, which will re-start it. Then put `/etc/init.d/script monitor` or `service script monitor` in a cron job in your liking interval

Comment: is this correct for the monitor) the else part will be $0 start correct ? I don understand this part when your said /etc/init.d script monitor is it a new script or the monitor) section is in the same old script ?

Comment: @biz14 something like that: http://pastebin.com/n6YGCEg8

Comment: ok I got it very clear and very interesting. How will the monitor operate by itself on what interval it will be doing the check if the process and pidfile exist ?

Comment: @biz14 it will work at the exact interval you'll set in the `cron` job you're going to create to run it...

Comment: ok I will try it out and update you accordingly.

Comment: supposed should this script on restart or must I still go n service pc.sh start? Cause once I restart it started by itself and secondly it did not start something strange right?